# writing a map as template with Pair and iterator c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dictionary

A little help please with this task, I need to write a simplified map template with `Pair` class and iterator class, I'm a beginner and I'm really messy and troubled with this, I would be glad for some help only with the header.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include "Exceptions.h"


template <typename DataType>
    struct Node {
      DataType        data;
      Node<DataType> *next;
      };

namespace mtm {

template <class KeyType, class ValueType, class CompareFunction = std::less<KeyType> >

class MtmMap {
public:
    class Pair {
    public:
        Pair(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value)
            : first(key), second(value){}
        const KeyType first;
        ValueType second;
        ~Pair() = default;
        Pair* begin();
        Pair* end();
        void insert();
        void insert(const KeyType&, const ValueType&);
        void remove(const KeyType&);
        bool containsKey(const KeyType& key) const;
        int size() const;
        Pair& operator=(const Pair&) = default;
        ValueType& operator[](const KeyType&);
        const ValueType& operator[](const KeyType&) const;
        Pair& operator[]();

    /*private:
    Node<Pair> _pairs;
    int _size;
    */
    };
    class iterator{
    /*private:
        Pair *cur_itr;
        Node<Pair*> pair_ptr;
    */
    public:
        iterator();
        iterator(const Pair*);
        iterator(const iterator&);
        ~iterator();
        iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = default;
        iterator& operator++(int);
        iterator& operator++();
        iterator& operator*();
        bool operator==(const iterator&);
    };

    bool operator!=(const iterator&, const iterator&);
};



}
```

I was given an empty part, like this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include "Exceptions.h"

namespace mtm {

template <class KeyType, class ValueType, class CompareFunction = std::less<KeyType> >
class MtmMap {
public:
    class Pair {
    public:
        Pair(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value)
            : first(key), second(value) {}
        const KeyType first;
        ValueType second;
    };
};

}
```

And the first part is after I wrote all the needed for realization operators and functions. Notice that it is pretty simplified version of map container, so I only need this part, **WITHOUT USING ANY STL**.

Can somebody help with writing the private fields and other things that belongs to the structure of the template class `MtmMap` ???

The idea using a list struct is mine, as I need list of operators and pairs as a container, as I can see it.

Any other ideas, comments, and stuff will be excellent and I'll be grateful, thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify my question, before I'll continue to the cpp file for realization, I'm stuck, because I don't understand how I should realize all the functions of the map, how to storage them and etc. 
I need help finishing this header.

Comment: anyone, little help ?

Comment: You need help finishing the *header?* What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. As posted right now, the only correct answer would be the one providing you the whole written header file. Waht art of it do you need hel with?

Comment: As I understand, I need to accomplish the private fields and I don't know how to translate my ideas into code. For example what should I put in private field of Pairs ? 
What I want is to have a list of pairs and a size (which counts how many there is)? Should I write it as in my comments, just make "size" static in Pair class ?

2. about the iterator, as I understand I need an internal and external iterator, one for delivering outside and one for myself, for example to check if the map containes a key value, is the idea correct ?
In comments I tried this idea, but I don't sure if it's correct

Comment: So maybe do one Node<iterator> as private and one as public.

Comment: Why are you adding the functionality to `Pair`? That should be a simple type with just the key and value. The actual map-related functions should be in `MtmMap`. It will help to look at `std::map`. Not actually use it in your code, but the documentation to see how it's organized.

Comment: You are trying to do too much at once. If what you want is a list of Pairs (which sounds good to me) then I suggest you create a list of `int`, get that working perfectly, then attempt a list of `Pair`. And once that's working perfectly, you can add the other functions a Map ought to have.